# Add to database with mysql, ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a file cart.html which displayes a list of items fetched from database and each item has a button 'AddToCart' which when clicked call the function addDB() and add the product to the table product_add.
My problem is that when the button 'AddToCart' is clicked only nulll values are inserted in the table product_add .

```
//This function is found in the cart.html and get the items from the database
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#product").click(function() {                

  $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "GET",
    url: "allProducts.php",             
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
    success: function(response){                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        //alert(response);
    }

});
});
});


 //the above function is called when a button 'View All Products' is clicked
 <input type="button" id="cart" value="View Cart"/>
```

The above code works fine and displayes the result

```
//These lines of codes are in the allProducts.php
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td><img src=".$row['image']."  width='120' height='100'/></td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['price']."</td>";
    echo "<td>";


    echo "<input type='button' value='Add to Cart' onclick='addDB()'/>";    

    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

Here is the function addDB()

```
function addDB() {
var request = $.ajax({
url: "add.php",
type: "GET",           
dataType: "html"
});



request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});

 };
```

This is the add.php

```
 <?php

include 'dbConnect.php';

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$price= isset($_GET['price']) ? $_GET['price'] : "";

$insert = "INSERT INTO product_add(id, name, price) VALUES ('$id', '$name','$price')";
$insertQuery=mysql_query($insert);
?>
```

My problem is that when the button 'AddToCart is clicked' null or 0 are being inserted in the database.Can somebody please help me ?

Comment: wow, **sql injection**

Comment: Watch out. Your code is vulnerable to [sql injections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: obviously , you are not sending any data

Comment: Injection vulnerabilities asside, GET params are found in the URI, your URI is `add.php`, when it should be `add.php?id=123&name=foobar&price=456`, or `$.ajax({data: {id:123, name: 'foobar', price: 456});` in jQuery-lingo. But first of all: ***stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` extension, and fix that gaping injection vulnerability***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending any data to the php-page. A simple approach would be to pass them via GET-Parameters in the url of you AJAX-Call:

```
function addDB(id, name ,price) {
     var request = $.ajax({
          url: "add.php?id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&price=" + price,
          type: "GET"    
     });
     request.done(function() {
         alert("Ajax call done.");
     });
}
```

Also, your code is vulnerable to [sql-injections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Please do ALWAYS use [prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

You modified add.php would then look like this:

```
 <?php

     include 'dbConnect.php';

     $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
     $name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
     $price= isset($_GET['price']) ? $_GET['price'] : "";

     $query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO product_add(id, name, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
     $query->bind_param("isi", $id, $name, $price);
     $query->execute();
     $query->close();
?>
```

You would of course have to initialize the object "$mysqli" somehow in your file dbConnect.php in order to use it.